# Why changing value in component file(.ts) not rendering in template file(.html)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

I tried to change a value in component file, but the current and updated value not rendered in the template file. Here is my Code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'cr-content-upload',
  templateUrl: './app/template.html'
})
export class ContentUploadComponent {
  constructor( ) { }  

  toggleContent:boolean = false; 
  updateContent(data:any) {
      if(data == "streaming") {
         this.toggleContent = true;
         console.log(this.toggleContent);
      }
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  } 
}
```

and here is my template.html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="updateContent('streaming')">
<div *ngIf="toggleContent">
    This is sample Content
</div>
```

Note: When the value is logged to console, it prints the updated value. But, the updated value doesn't get rendered into template.html file.
And also i get this issue in many occasion. So, kindly provide solution and also reason for the issue.

Comment: are you saying the div is not getting toggled?

Comment: @SASIKUMARS I just mentioned only one variable here, but i do the same for many variables. So, I cant return one variable.

Comment: Is your HTML valid? You didn't close `<a>` tag in your example. It should work otherwise [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y0KWV671pijweFxYZdAs?p=preview)

Comment: Try this as there is "no text for Href to click" Code `<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="updateContent('streaming')">Test</a>
<div *ngIf="toggleContent">
    This is sample Content
</div>`

To Use Toggling in ts use below code
`this.toggleContent = !this.toggleContent; // Toggle`

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, but if your template isn't detecting the changes, you could try and use [**`ChangeDetectorRef`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detectChanges-anchor).

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core'
```

and in your component inject it to your constructor and use it after setting your boolean to `true`.

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef)

updateContent(data:any) {
  if(data == "streaming") {
     this.toggleContent = true;
     this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
   }
}
```